# Codeigniter active record insert return value

Tags: sql, codeigniter, return-value

It's been months since i've actively coded. So i forgot some things. I tried looking at active records in user guide but it doesn't state return values of the queries.

Is it okay to write an insert function like this?

Assuming that the return value of any successful insert query is TRUE and an unsuccessful insert would return FALSE.

```
public function insert_user($data){
 return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

or

```
public function insert_user($data){
 if($this->db->insert('users', $data)){
  return TRUE; 
 } 
 else { return FALSE; } 
 }
```

On my second approach, doesn't it assume in the if statement that it is TRUE/False therefore the return value should be true/false in the first place? so it would be redundant to check if it was true then return true or false then return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you overlooked the section [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#CI_DB_query_builder::insert) - because it clearly states it returns `true` or `false`. So in your case - your first approach is fine.

However one thing should be considered here. Most of the time you do have an auto increment column (unique id or something like that) - in this case it suits better to get your id back immediately.

An example would be:

```
public function insert_user($data)
{
    return ($this->db->insert('users', $data))  ?   $this->db->insert_id()  :   false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if it took too long. I took an unexpected procastination break. 

Anyways, i was just skimming the page so yea i missed it. I do remember using the find(ctrl+f) function in chrome, i forgot what keyword i put in though.

To your advice, if i understood it clearly, you mean it's better for me to check if an id(auto incremented - all of my Primary Key are AI for example: user_id(PK,AI) for user table, etc.) is returned rather than the result if the query is successful(returns true/false)?